# Using Delete http command in service

Tags: angular

I would like to know something related to delete functionality. Refer the following code:-

```
// Method in service
 delete(Id: string): Observable<any> {
        this.Url = 'http://locahost:8080/...';
        return this.http.delete(this.Url)
            .map((response:Response) => response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    // Method in component
    deleteFromComp(Id: string): void {
    this.subscriptions.push(this.MyService.delete(Id).subscribe(
      data => {
      },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error, () => { }
    ));

    this.CallServciceToGetDataFromServer(this.PageRequestModel);
  }
```

The delete method calls server side code to delete a record and nothing is being returned.

I have the following two questions:-

1. If nothing is getting returned, why there is a need to subscribe? Is it just for 200 message code?
2. The following modified call does not work:-

   ```
   // Method in component
           deleteFromComp(Id: string): void {
           this.subscriptions.push(this.MyService.delete(Id).subscribe(
             data => {
               this.CallServciceToGetDataFromServer(this.PageRequestModel);
             },
             error => this.errorMessage = <any>error, () => { }
           ));

         }
   ```

Comment: If there's nothing in the response it should be 204 NO CONTENT, not 200 OK. And you need to subscribe because all the http methods are cold observables, they don't make a request until there's a subscriber.

Comment: was just about to say about cold observables, read more about observables here: https://angular.io/guide/observables

Comment: thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
deleteFromComp(Id: string): void {
        this.subscriptions.push(this.MyService.delete(Id).subscribe(
          () => {
            this.CallServciceToGetDataFromServer(this.PageRequestModel);
          },
          error => this.errorMessage = <any>error, () => { }
        ));

      }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t subscribe to `observables` they are not going to execute

Since with `httpClient` all the `HTTP requests` return `observables`, you should `subscribe` to them

**Subscribing to observables:**

> Remember, observables are lazy. If you don’t subscribe nothing is
>   going to happen. It’s good to know that when you subscribe to an
>   observer, each call of subscribe() will trigger it’s own independent
>   execution for that given observer. Subscribe calls are not shared
>   among multiple subscribers to the same observable.

[**Here is a helpful link**](https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-creating-and-subscribing-to-observables-in-angular-426dbf0b04a3)

Here is an example snippet:

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable"
// create observable
const simpleObservable = new Observable((observer) => {
    // observable execution
    observer.next("bla bla bla")
    observer.complete()
})
// subscribe to the observable
simpleObservable.subscribe()
// dispose the observable
simpleObservable.unsubscribe()
```

In this untill you subscribe, i.e until you call `simpleObservable.subscribe()` that wont get execute.

**PS:**

One of the main uses to use `subscribe`, that is important to check the `delete status`, for example what if `backend` throws you an `error`, then you can check the status using `res.status` or `response.success` or `error` in `error` callback

Comment: From api they might not be returning anything, but still as `delete` is `http method`, it returns an observable

Comment: I got my answer and it appears the code can me modified as follows:-deleteFromComp(Id: string): void {
    this.subscriptions.push(this.MyService.delete(Id).subscribe());
    this.CallServciceToGetDataFromServer(this.PageRequestModel);
  }

Comment: yes, so you should subscribe to that. That's the solution. Thats your wish that you want any data or not from that

Comment: I have subscribed for sure but I was not sure, what is the correct way as I could see that return type if observable<any> and delete method not returning anything from server so this was bit confusing but I have better info on this scenario. thanks a ton to everyone.

Comment: that is important to check the delete status, for example what if backend throws you an error, then you can check the status using `res.status` or `response.success` or error in `error` callback